# Outer div element is not expanded correctly

Tags: html, css

Why does the outer element not hug the child element?
the top and bottom are too small and the right side is way out there.

I want an outer border for contrast. I was hoping that using a simple div or span block would work. I've visited what seems like an innumerable number of sites, but I never see any results like this. This renders this same way in both chrome and edge.

Buttons and other elements are by default have differing properties, there doesn't seem to be an exhaustive list anywhere: this would be helpful too.

[image: Un expected results]

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<style>
body { 
  background: lightblue;

}
.border {
    display:inline;
    border-width: 2px;
    border-style: solid;
}
.button {
    font-family : Arial;
    font-size : 16px;
    font-weight : normal;
    border-width: 2px;
    border-style: solid;
    border-color: red;
    text-align: center;
    background-color: white;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
}
</style>
</head>
<body>
    <div class="border">
        <button class="button">Actual BTN</button>
    </div>
    <span class="border">
        <span class="button">Span 4 BTN</span>
    </span> 
    <button class="button">Naked BTN</button>
    <span class="button">Naked span BTN</span>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Can you elaborate on the problem? I don't understand what you mean by "the top and bottom are too small and the right side is way out there"

Comment: @j08691 I was expecting the first two elements to be tightly bounded in a black rectangle. If you look at the picture, the top row is what's rendered. the bottom row is what I expected. Then follow the orange-ish arrows, they show the gaps that I was not expecting, which is in addition to the top and bottom problems.

Comment: You have white space in your code between the divs and button/span. Remove the white space and the gaps disappear. https://jsfiddle.net/j08691/q1jbtunr/. You also want inline-block instead of inline if you want the top and bottom to appear https://jsfiddle.net/j08691/q1jbtunr/1/

Comment: @j08691 Thanks, that clears up the gaps. But what about the top and bottom of the first two elements clipping the outer element border?

Comment: See my second fiddle in the above comment

Comment: @j08691 Thank you, I missed the second link, obviously. I appreciate the help!